# Can emacs org-mode be made to treat lines starting with % as comments?

Tags: emacs, comments, org-mode

I know that I can mark a line as a comment in org-mode by prefixing it with `#`. Is it possible to configure the same behaviour for lines beginning with `% '?

Comment: You may not think this a real answer, but it is ... **don't**. Just use `#`

Comment: @Slomojo: if you think that really is an answer post it as an answer and see how the votes go.  Personally I agree with you but I'm not impressed by your timidity.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I'm impressed with your goading.

Comment: Ubiquitous, you had better provide some context if there's a valid reason for the question, because Slomojo's response is hard to argue with. (Are you trying to incorporate a large amount of existing data with `%` comments in it, for example?)

Comment: My reasoning is that I would like an `.org` file in which I can keep a lot of notes related to a project. Some of these notes will be snippets written in various languages, including LaTeX and Mathematica. I would like to be able to copy and paste the latex passages straight into `.tex` files without having to do any manipulation to reformat them as LaTeX comments.

Comment: Doesn't Babel provide for embedding code for pretty much any language into an org file?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried modifying the following function from `org.el`:

```lisp
(defun org-at-comment-p nil
  "Is cursor in a line starting with a # character?"
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (looking-at "^#")))
```

By changing the regular expression for something like `^[#%]`, with no luck.

The `#` character is hardcoded in *many* places within org-mode.

Comment: Neither setting the variable `comment-start` to "%" seems to help.

Answer (score 2):

You may not think this a real answer, but it is ...

**Don't, just use #**

Answer (score 2):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
  'org-mode `(("^[ \t]*\\(#\\)[ +\n].*$"
      (0 (compose-region
      (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) ?%)))))
```

This displays a `%` character even though it is a `#` character.  You still need to insert comments with #, but they will be displayed like you want.